# why @HystrixCommand which is the annotation of spring injected is failed?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, hystrix

The pom file of my service which is maven project as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>hello</groupId>
<artifactId>reading</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

And the part source code of my service as follows:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "reliable")
public String readingList(){
    URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8090/recommended");

    return this.restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
}
```

My question is, when I import `com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand`, it is not recognized. Anyone encountered this same problem?

Please tell me about how did you resolved it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest POM file, it has been deprecated in favour of `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix`. STS didn't help me to add the import either, so you might need to add it manually:

```
import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand;
```